# UVC Extension Unit transfert only one byte of data?

Tags: com, webcam

I am using UVC extension Unit between Windows7 / Windows xp and Custom device.

To access the custom device I am using the following COM interface :

```
KSP_NODE  s;
s.Property.Set = Guid_KSPROPSETID;
s.Property.Id = PropID;
s.Property.Flags = KSPROPERTY_TYPE_GET | KSPROPERTY_TYPE_TOPOLOGY;
s.NodeId = dwExtensionNode;
hr = pIKsControl->KsProperty( (PKSPROPERTY) &s, sizeof(s), pbPropertyValue, ulSize, &ulBytesReturned);
```

It works fine, but at the Windows UVC side I can't transfert more than one byte instead of the complete buffer `pbPropertyValue` of ulSize size. Someone know why? And how to fix it?

One more question, I am trying to find how to access the `UVC_GET_MIN, UVC_GET_MAX, UVC_GET_INFO, UVC_GET_DEF and UVC_GET_RES` with Extension unit? With the standard property I am using `pVideoProcAmp->GetRange` Method. But I didn't find the equivalent for the extension unit.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, the problem was coming from the UVC_GEN_LEN return value.
The length need to be = 0x02;
And the data back needed to be equal to the len of the ulSize..